# Webapp using ASP/NET and MySQL

Tags: .net, mysql

in these days I'm going to evaluate pros and cons in choosing the software requirements of a web application wich will be potentially scale very faster (imagine a farm of 100 servers).
As you can imagine, a drive aspect of my choice is about the costs.

Here my own consideration:
[+] ASP.NET is a very robust, efficient and well supported platform that make me confident to easily find skilled personnel in the future. Even the velocity is another attractive aspect.

[-] The best performance (not only in terms of CPU but even in term of economics and productivity) are gained on the proprietary platform. The cost of webserver licenses is affordable in comparison to the benefit earned on other expensive factors.

On the backend side, on the other end, SQLServer is very expensive and for many regards it is overestimated. MySQL satisfies me for the license costs, features and performance. It seems it well support even .NET environment so...

So, I'm taking into serious consideration to make this decision that, I've to be honest, leave me a bit sucked... :)

I've worked on LAMP and M$ worlds, yes, a bit of integration, but never taking a so radical decision from the ground.

Does someone heard of a serious project implemented in this way?
I'll appreciate any feedback, consideration and criticism.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be looking at success stories instead. You can get horror stories about pretty much anything that you want, and you'll usually not know enough about why it really failed for them.

If you are already set with using .net I'd forget about that part of the decision, and move on to the specific issue of mysql vs. sql server.

The question really boils down to if mysql supports the scale that you need well, and if you have any other special requirements from it. Unfortunately I haven't used mysql in such scale, but I think looking for this info directly should give you the answer you need.

Comment: That is what I'm looking for but unfortunately google doesn't seem to offer

Comment: Essentially what I was asking for... :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem using MySql together with .Net. MySql has a set of very mature .Net connector classes that work very well.